# Where do Mooshrooms spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This question is about normal vanilla minecraft in survival mode. I've noticed that mooshrooms seem to only spawn on mushroom islands. Is my guess correct, or is there another set of parameters in which they can spawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will spawn only on mycelium biomes, and the only mycelium biome in vanilla minecraft is a mushroom island. Also, as KenzoEngineer said, the only other way to spawn them is through commands and spawn eggs, which are not natural in vanilla survival.

Comment: Adding to your answer it's also good to note that just placing mycelium (obtainable in survival through the silk touch enchantment) in a non mushroom biome biome would not allow for mooshrooms to spawn

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. Mooshrooms can only spawn on mushroom islands. The only other ways would be to spawn them in with spawn eggs, or using the `/summon` command in a format like:

`/summon MushroomCow`.
You can of course bring the Mooshrooms away from the island onto the main land with wheat or leads.